# How to grab mplayer output to file?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, output, mplayer, fifo

I need something like this:
When I'll redirect command by FIFO to mplayer `echo "get_property volume" > /tmp/fifo` I want to have this command output in `output.txt`, e.g `ANS_volume=100`.

I have tried something like this
`mplayer -slave -quiet -idle -input file=/tmp/fifo file.mp3 > /tmp/output.txt`

But this doesn't work - file is empty.
I saw a few people did this in this way but in my case this isn't working.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Why don't use `echo "get_property volume" | tee -a output.txt > /tmp/fifo`

Comment: Because then I get only `get_property volume` in file

Answer (score -1):

Question: do you need to put your command in double quotes not single? From the man page of mplayer:

```
                  file=<filename>
                  Read commands from the given file.  Mostly useful with a
                  FIFO.
                  NOTE: When the given file is a FIFO MPlayer  opens  both
                  ends  so  you  can do several 'echo "seek 10" > mp_pipe'
                  and the pipe will stay valid.
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using double quotes. I did a mistake in a post. Sorry.